# Nginx location to override a Laravel 5.2 route?

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, nginx, server

I have an nginx web server serving a Laravel 5.2 app on port 80.

By going to mydomain.com my laravel app kicks in and everything is working as intended.

On the other hand, I have a nodejs application running on port 83 that serves other type of content.
The problem comes when I want to serve my nodejs content throught a reverse proxy on the main domain.

What I'm trying to do is get nginx to serve at domain.com/api/info/socket my nodejs app without laravel trying to parse that url with it's routing system. Here is my nginx configuration to try and do so:

```
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        #access_log /var/log/nginx/access_log combined;
        #index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    server {

        # SSL configuration

        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        include snippets/ssl-mydomain.com.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access_log combined;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html

        server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

        location / {
            root /var/www/mydomain.com/public;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location /stream {
            proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            proxy_read_timeout      300;
            proxy_pass              http://localhost:9999/stream;
        }

        # This will not let laravel parse this url. replace index.html if you have some other entry point.
        location /api/info/socket {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /api/info/socket/index.html;
        }

        location = /api/info/socket {
            proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            proxy_read_timeout      300;
            proxy_pass              http://localhost:83;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            set $php_root /var/www/mydomain.com/public;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $php_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
        }
    }
```

But everytime I visit that URL I get the laravel 404 error message since it's not a part of my routes configuration. Any idea on how to force nginx to serve that specific url without letting Laravel take over?

Comment: Do you have access to create a dns entry for a subdomain? May simplify it for you.

Comment: That could certainly help, but I want to keep all my public endpoints under domain.com/api if possible

Comment: Could use `api.domain.com` and forward the requests on the main domain. Isn't it `proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;` ? Are you listening on `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Also, you may want to use `proxy_pass              $scheme://localhost:83;` so that you don't redirect all traffic away from https

Comment: @Blake I enforce https by redirecting from http to https, is the $scheme still needed then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine. You just need to add few lines.

```
server_name domain.com www.domain.com;    
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html

location / {
root /var/www/domain.com/public;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

# This will not let laravel parse this url. replace index.html if you have some other entry point.
#location /api/info/socket {
#    try_files $uri $uri/ /api/info/socket/index.html;
#}

# If above doesn't work try this.
location /api/info/socket/ {
     try_files $uri $uri/ @api;
}
location @api {
     rewrite /api/info/socket/ /api/info/socket/index.html;
}

location = /api/info/socket {
proxy_set_header        Host $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

proxy_read_timeout      300;
proxy_pass              http://localhost:83;
}

# This is the php processing needed for laravel
location ~ \.php$ {
#include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
set $php_root /var/www/mydomain.com/public;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index  index.php;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $php_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Also, you need to place your node application into public directory and don't forget to restart nginx `sudo service nginx restart`
Let me know if it solved your problem. :)

Comment: I made this changes but I'm still having the same issue. Would it be better if I post my entire default config and not just the relevant server block?

Comment: I just updated the main question with additional info. May I point out that /stream doesn't get parsed by laravel and works as intended, which is really odd. I'm also restarting with **sudo systemctl restart nginx**, dont know if it changes anything. Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: okay, tell me what url you want to be like ? `mydomain.com/api` or `mydomain.com/api/info/socket` ? and what url you're trying to access ?

Comment: Right now my Laravel app parses several urls like:

mydomain.com/api/info/poll, so the new url I want to access without laravel interfering is mydomain.com/api/info/socket . Right now I'm trying to access that url and I get the default 404 from Laravel.

Comment: and what's the entry file on `/api/info/socket` ? `index.html` or something else ?

Comment: Yeah there's a nodejs app just serving a index.html file on /

Comment: I've update the answer. see if that works. I'm using same configuration for my own site and its works perfectly.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, I'm getting the exact same results after applying your changes and restarting nginx with sudo systemctl restart nginx. Would it be useful for me to link the actual website? I'm new here and stack just told me to avoid long discussions on comments :/

Comment: Alright @imrealashu I managed to get it working with your code but now when I visit mydomain.com/api/info/socket all I get is **Cannot GET /api/info/socket**

Comment: so I guess its working. check your node code for `/` root route

Comment: Thanks for the help, now I just need to figure out why the reverse proxy is not working as intended. Thank you!

Comment: Glad i could @Kanadeko. Let me know if you need help again with anything. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to move `location /api/info/socket` block above `location /`

Comment: Just tried that and I'm getting the exact same issue, Laravel's 404 page. I also modified the location block by adding = as the documentation suggests for exact matches but it's not working either.

Comment: Replace `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;`
with
`try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve the issue either :(

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me :)